# Adding class alongside id in Ajax sucess

Tags: php, ajax

So on success I have content that goes into a div that has both an id and class in PHP and because the class has css attached it needs to be also added on Ajax success..

```
<div id="notif_actual_text-<? echo $notificationchant['notification_id'] ?>" class="notif_actual_text">
```

So my question is. How do I add `class="notif_actual_text"`to

```
 $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the element with that id AND with that class:

```
 $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id+".notif_actual_text");
```

If you want to add that class to that id:

```
 $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id).addClass('notif_actual_text');
```